# Site funciona no localhost, mas não no UolHost (permissões?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Criei um site padrão (daqueles que já vêm pré codificados do visual studio 2013), utilizando tecnologia asp.net mvc com autenticação comum por contas individuais.

No meu localhost o site roda que é uma beleza, cadastra usuários, confiro no banco de dados e está tudo perfeito.

Porém quando publico para o uol host, na hora de logar com um usuário cadastrado, ele dá problema de permissão (print: http://s18.postimg.org/fm2qw8gzt/print.png)

Não acredito que seja necessário ter full trust para rodar uma aplicação tão básica, senão não seria possível hospedar asp.net mvc em quase nenhum servidor comercial. Deve ser alguma configuração (não funciona se eu definir trust level = full no webconfig pois o uol host não permite essa mudança).

Já tentei de tudo que se pode imaginar, mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar.

Alguém já teve esse problema antes e pode me dar uma luz?

Descrição do erro:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory`1+d__0.MoveNext()' to access security critical method 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(System.Security.Claims.Claim)' failed.
>
> Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory`1+d__0.MoveNext()' to access security critical method 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.AddClaim(System.Security.Claims.Claim)' failed.
>
> Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas te digo uma coisa, existe mais de uma maneira de se fazer algo (é só uma teoria)

Comment: Sei que isso nao acrescenta nada a pergunta, mas esse winspymonitor parece ser um "pouco" invasão de privacidade. "Veja Perfis de Facebook visitados" '-'

Comment: @user2000542 pode me ajudar a configurar o .net MVC para fazer conexao com o localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar o código abaixo no seu `web.config`

`<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>`

Já tive um problema parecido e esse código resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar adicionar a configuração abaixo no seu web.config, dentro da tag System.web:

```
<trust level="medium" originUrl="" />
```

Mas isso pode não funcionar em alguns hosts, pois os mesmos bloqueiam essa configuração.

Não custa testar.

Comment: Não funciona, o padrão do servidor já é medium.